# rhino mocks mocking a call

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

I have a method that I want to test which hits the database.  From what I have read this is a perfect oppurtunity to use a mock.  However the problem that I am facing is that I pass the object a string and then it creates an object and hits the db with this object i.e.

```
public void test(string t)
{
   Test t1 = new Test(t);
   db.Save(t1);
}
```

Then the in the test I have:

```
using(mockery.Record)
{
   Expect.Call(db.Save( ??? ))
}
```

The problem being - what do I expect here?  A call to:

```
Expect.call(db.Save(new Test(t))
```

does not work.

As I am new to mocking this may be an easy question, but any help will be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: btw I am mocking with ITest = mockery.StrictMock<ITest>(); I have got other mocks to work successfully, just not this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well often you pass the actual instance which you later expect. For example:

```
public void test(string t)
{
    Test t1 = new Test(t);
    using(mockery.Record)
    {
       Expect.Call(db.Save(t1));
    }
    using(mockery.Playback()
    {       
        db.Save(t1);
    }
    mockery.VerifyAll();
}
```

But this is maybe to limiting. Then you can actually define criterias which the argument has to fullfill. For example:

```
using(mockery.Record)
{
   Test instanceToCompare = new Test(t);    
   Expect.Call(db.Save(Arg<Test>.Is.Equal(instanceToCompare)));
}
```

Or another example:

```
using(mockery.Record)
{
   Expect.Call(db.Save(Arg<Test>.Matches(t=>t.Name.Length.Equals("Test"))));        
}
```